# wordpress register nav menu not showing in admin

Tags: menus, wp-admin

I am using the following code to register a menu for my theme. In functions.php I have written the following:

```
register_nav_menu( 'header-menu', __( 'Header Menu' ) );
```

When going into wp-admin >appearance > menus, the menu is not showing up.

Can anyone telll me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where have you added that code in `functions.php`? Inside a callback hooked into an appropriate action, or just directly in the file? Also, what do you mean by "the menu does not show up"? What **do** you see? Have you created any custom nav menus yet?

Comment: @ChipBennett I have added it on its own, not inside a callback. However, I have also tried to put it inside a callback as well:

`function register_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('header-menu', __('Header Menu'));
 }
 add_action('init', 'register_menu');`

Comment: The correct action to hook into is `after_setup_theme`. But I think this is an Admin UI issue. Have you created any custom nav menus yet?